# How to obtain the statement type OCI_ATTR_SQLFNCODE *before* OCIStatementExecute()?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-call-interface

I need to know how to obtain the statement type of a prepared statement handle in OCI.

The dilemna is as follows.  The fourth argument of `OCIStmtExecute()` - `iters` - cannot be `0` if the statement is not a `SELECT`, but it *must* be `0` if the statement *is* a `SELECT` (and defines cannot be done ahead of time).  From the OCI 10g documentation for `OCIStmtExecute`:

> For non-SELECT statements, the number of times this statement is
>   executed is equal to iters - rowoff.
>
> For SELECT statements, if iters is nonzero, then defines must have
>   been done for the statement handle. The execution fetches iters rows
>   into these predefined buffers and prefetches more rows depending upon
>   the prefetch row count. If you do not know how many rows the SELECT
>   statement will retrieve, set iters to zero.
>
> This function returns an error if iters=0 for non-SELECT statements.

For a statement such as `SELECT * ...`, it is impossible to know what the columns even *are* before obtaining the `describe` information from the statement handle, which is only available after `OCIStmtExecute()` is called.  (So, it's not possible to do `defines` on the statement handle ahead of time.)  Therefore, I must pass `0` for `iters` if the (unknown) statement type is `SELECT`.  But if the (unknown) statement type is *not* `SELECT`, OCI returns an error if `iters` is `0` (just as the documentation says).

The documented way to obtain the type of statement (`SELECT` or not) is by querying an attribute of the statement handle, as follows:

```
ub2 statementType = 0;
OCIAttrGet(mystmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (dvoid*)(&statementType), NULL, OCI_ATTR_SQLFNCODE, myerrhp);
```

Unfortunately, this function *always* returns `0` for `statementType` until *after* `OCIStmtExecute()` is called.

I am in a catch-22 situation.  I must call `OCIAttrGet()` before I call `OCIStmtExecute()` to obtain the type of statement in order to set `iters` properly.  However, I must call `OCIStmtExecute()` before `OCIAttrGet()` will succeed.

I have tried calling `OCIStmtExecute()` twice, the first time passing `OCI_DESCRIBE_ONLY` for the final parameter (`mode`).  Unfortunately, `OCIStmtExecute()` *still* gives the error related to `iters` in this case.

(Please note: the statement handle `mystmt` has been properly prepared ahead of time, successfully, with a call to `OCIStmtPrepare2()`, and the error handle `myerrhp` has also been properly allocated.)

What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE` instead: It is available right after `OCIStmtPrepare` and can be used to crudely determine the type of statement (ie. also if this is a "select" statement).