# How to determine if a script is DML? OCI?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, oracle-call-interface, dml

My goal is to somehow be sending (Maybe via an OCI) process an sql script to determine whether if it is a DML script (All of the code blocks are not DDL nor DCL) or an hybrid with other data languages.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Let's say maybe with OCI you can't do it. How would you automatically do a check to validate this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE` as explained by https://stackoverflow.com/a/13528133/103724 and you will get one of the values in this table http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci04sql.htm#CIHEHCEJ.

There's also `OCI_ATTR_SQLFNCODE` which provides more detailed information, but as the question above showed, it can be tricky to use. --DD